# Error: cannot read properties of null (reading "dataId1")

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, entity-framework-core

I want to write a code in Angular which passes two parameters into a CREATE method in C# EF Core. However, I want the users to be able to set the values for the parameters in a dialogbox. The values should be set by two dropdown lists of selectable items (one for each of the two parameters)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is my code so far:

```
getDataforId1(){
    let companyId = +(this.authService.getCompany('id') || 0);
    this.dataService.getDataforId1(companyId).subscribe((res) =>{
      this.item = res || [];
      for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        if (res[i].value == this.dialogData.data.dataId1) {
          this.itemName = res[i].value
        }
      }
    })
  }

getDataforId2(){
    let companyId = +(this.authService.getCompany('id') || 0);
    this.dataService.getTransport(companyId).subscribe((res) =>{
      this.item = res || [];
      for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        if (res[i].value == this.dialogData.data.dataId2) {
          this.itemName = res[i].value
        }
      }
    })
  }
```

The onSubmit code looks like this:

```
onSubmit() {
    const data = this.form.value
    if (this.form.valid) {
      this.routePlannerService.createItem(data, this.dataId1, this.dataId2, this.stageId).subscribe((res) => {
        this.toastService.success(this.stageId ? 'language.update_successfully' : 'language.add_successfully');
        this.dialogRef.close(res);
      }, () => {
        this.loadingService.hide();
      });
    }
  }
```

The Service code in Angular:

```
createDataRegistration(data: any, dataId1: number, dataId2: number, stageId?: number) {
    if(stageId) {
      return this.http.put(
        `DataHeading/DataRegistration?dataID=${stageId}&dataId1=${dataId1}&dataId2=${dataId2}`,
        data
      );
    }
    return this.http.post(`DataHeading/DataRegistration?dataHeadingID=${this.dataHeadingId}&dataId1=${dataId1}&dataId2=${dataId2}`, data);
  }
```

The Backend Endpoint:

```
[HttpPost("DataRegistration")]
public int CreateDataRegistration(int dataHeadingID, long dataId1, long dataLinkId2, DataRegistrationModel model)
{
    return _dataHeadingService.CreateDataRegistrations(dataHeadingID, dataId1, dataId2, model);
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.